# Mode of sum of two random variables (RVs) v.s. Mode of each RV

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, convolution

I wonder is there any literature or answer of the following relationship.

What I want to know is whether the maximum peak of $\mathbf{X}+\mathbf{Y}$ is reasonably close to the maximum peak of $\mathbf{X}$. Suppose the following things.

- $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$ are two random variables on the same probability space
- $\mathbf{X}$ should be any arbitrary distribution, while $\mathbf{Y}$ is unimodal (or uniform distribution within some range).
- $\mathbf{X}$ can have multiple modes, but there is only a single mode that has  a maximum probability.
- Doesn't matter whether discrete or continuous case
- for simplicity, $\mathbf{Y}$ has no shifted bias, i.e. zero-mean

Can I quantify or bound the position of the mode of $\mathbf{X}+\mathbf{Y}$ by the positions of the maximum mode of $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$? 
I don't want to get some simulation examples, which has been already checked by myself. What I'm interested in is an explicit inequality by each of mode. If any generic relationship doesn't exist, what will be the condition for that?

I appreciate in advance, thanks!

Comment: A general related topic is 'mixture distributions'. In particular, many mixture distributions are 'mult-modal'. You might google that, perhaps starting with the Wikipedia article

Comment: Thanks for you guy's comments. However, what I'm asking is even more profound. I exactly know what is mixture distribution. 
It is the same question like
"For an arbitrary signal that has multiple peaks, I want to know how peaks are shifted by low-pass filtering (you can assume any simple one). Is there any rigorous bound relationship?"

There must be some misleading points in my question. Now, I fixed it to be clear.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Also, the simulation result conducted by BruceET turns out supporting the existence of such relationship still.

Comment: In the case where $X$ is a mixture of two normal RVs and $Y$ is also normal, then you can write the density of $T$ which is again the mixture of two normals. You can see whether $T$ is still bimodal. If $Y$ adds greatly to the variances of the two normals that make up $T$ then there may be only one mode.

Answer (score 1):

**Comment.** (Certainly not a definitive answer.)

I tried one example of what I believe you described: The sum $T$ (bottom) of $X$, a bimodal mixture
distribution, and a normal distribution $Y$. It seems that $Y$ can control
the position of the mode(s) in $T.$ It shifts the mixture distribution to
the right by about 20 units and smears out its peaks a little. If the modes
of $X$ were closer together, then $T$ might not be bimodal. Here you can find
the PDF of $X$ and thus find the PDF of $T.$

[image]

Here is R code for this experiment, in case it is of any use to you.

```
 x1 = rnorm(1000, 50, 3);  x2 = rnorm(1000, 70, 5);  x = c(x1, x2)
 y = rnorm(2000, 20, 5);  t = x + y
 par(mfrow=c(3, 1))  # enables 3-panel plot
   hist(x, prob=T, col="skyblue2", xlim=c(0,100), 
        main="50:50 Mix of NORM(50,3) & NORM(70,5)")
   hist(y, prob=T, col="skyblue2", xlim=c(0,100), 
        main="NORM(20,5)")
   hist(t, prob=T, col="skyblue2", xlim=c(0,100), 
        main="SUM of Mix and NORM(20,5)")
 par(mfrow=c(1,1))  # returns to default single-panel plots
```

*Addendum:* You changed the question, so I am changing my "answer" to illustrate
my latest Comment beneath your Question But one cam play with simulated examples all day long without proving anything. *You need to derive the formulas of the density functions.* I have shown 'kernel density estimators' to give a rough idea.

[image]

R code for plotting the first density estimator.

```
lines(density(x), lwd=2, col="green4")
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It seems there must be some misleading of my question. I edited my question to further clarify. 
By your simulation, it still says my statement is true, i.e. can be bounded with a bias factor of $Y$.